# Скачивание apk через мобильный Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html5

Всем привет. Нужна помощь сообщества.

Появилась задача написать страничку для скачивания и установки `.apk` файлов из браузера на телефоны.

Суть заключалась в том, что бы на странице был список программ с чекбоксами и кнопкой установить. Т.е. выбираю нужные программы, нажимаю установить, они скачиваются и устанавливаются (предлагает установить).

Что же, подумал я и начал писать.

Написал `index.html` во внутрь засунул форму с десятками инпутов

```
<form  method=get action="#" name="chekcms">
<label class="heading">Выберите программу:<br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-files="http://site.ru/install/WhatsApp.apk" name="WhatsApp">WhatsApp<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-files="http://site.ru/install/Viber.apk" name="Viber">Viber<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-files="http://site.ru/install/Skype.apk" name="Skype">Skype<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-files="http://site.ru/install/Opera.apk" name="Opera">Opera<br/>
</form>
```

Думал скачивать файлы через `PHP`, но не тут то было, `PHP` позволяет скачивать файлы только по 1му, мне же это не подходило и я нашел решение через `JS` а именно [multi-download](https://github.com/sindresorhus/multi-download) , получаю ссылки с `data-files` инпута, после чего происходит скачивание выбранных приложений.

В десктопной версии все работает отлично, файлы скачиваются, обрадовавшись, я взял телефон, зашел в хром, но у меня ничего не получилось, файлы не скачивались, но форма обрабатывалась. Почему так происходит - не могу понять.

Буду рад если подскажете в какую сторону копать.

P.S. В будущем я собираюсь сделать из этой страницы `.apk` файл, который будет выполнять ту же задачу, только пользователю не нужно будет запускать браузер - все будет делаться с .apk приложения.